# using mkfifo in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, mkfifo

I was trying to do something simple with a FIFO: read the lines, but not all at once, and it unexpectedly "did not work".

This is OK:

```
$ f=$(mktemp -u)
$ mkfifo $f
$ { seq 5 > $f; } &
[1] 2486
$ while read line; do echo $line; done < $f
1
2
3
4
5
[1]+  Done                    { seq 10 > $f; }
```

But if I try reading lines one-by-one, the first read succeeds and the 2nd read hangs.

```
$ { seq 5 > $f; } &
[1] 2527
$ read line < $f; echo $line
1
[1]+  Done                    { seq 5 > $f; }
$ read line < $f; echo $line
[hangs here...]
```

Can someone explain this? Why can't I read all 5 lines one-by-one? What happened to the rest of the data?

---

I discovered I can read line-by-line if I create a file descriptor to redirect the FIFO:

```
$ { seq 5 > $f; } &
[1] 2732
$ exec 3<$f
[1]+  Done                    { seq 5 > $f; }
$ read -u 3 line && echo $line || echo no more data
1
$ read -u 3 line && echo $line || echo no more data
2
$ read -u 3 line && echo $line || echo no more data
3
$ read -u 3 line && echo $line || echo no more data
4
$ read -u 3 line && echo $line || echo no more data
5
$ read -u 3 line && echo $line || echo no more data
no more data
$ exec 3<&-
```

I still don't understand the middle scenario. Can anyone explain?

---

Version info:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ mkfifo --version
mkfifo (GNU coreutils) 8.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

Comment: This could be related to version and bash vs ksh or ??. Can you add that info. (I won't know the answer in any case ;-( ). The most interesting question this quarter!

Comment: Exactly the same behaviour under OSX Mavericks and on a Ubuntu VirtualBox.

Comment: Your third scenario cannot be repro'd.

Comment: @devnull, really? what's your shell?

Comment: @glennjackman `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what happens is this:

`$ read line < $f` opens the FIFO for reading, reads one line, then closes the FIFO. Once the reader closes the FIFO on its side, the writer (`seq 5 > $f`) also closes. When you open the FIFO next time nobody writes to it at that point, so the `read` blocks.

With the `while` the FIFO is open for reading until the `while` command finishes, allowing the writer to send more lines to the FIFO.

You can use `lsof -p $$` to verify what files are (not) open at each point.

Comment: Thanks. I see the GNU info page says: "One process opens the FIFO file for writing, and another for reading" -- implying what you say.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is some confusion about `FIFO` here.

When you say:

```
read line < $f
```

it'd open the FIFO, seek, read, and be done with it after closing.  It doesn't matter whether you read a line or the entire data.

So when you attempt to read again, the `read` keeps waiting.

While it's waiting, try saying:

```
echo foo > $f
```

and you'd notice that the `read` is successful.

If you were monitoring the system calls being made in both the cases, you'd observe that the second `read` is waiting to read from the FIFO.

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here but your observation is pretty much along expected lines.